# How to detect server data changes without refreshing browser or using useEffect in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I'am fetching data from particular api consider some 'https://www.api-example.com' (just an example, not real url), with method:get, apiKey, authorization and all those things. Now to be more specific, the json data from the server is displayed to front side in React code, but, how to detect changes when json data changes after every minute or seconds or after hour or no changes.

Consider simple example, I am requesting for some Vide Call(VC) request to some person, and the data I receive from that person is in JSON format and has values such as `"vc_status":"accepted"` or `"vc_status":"rejected"` or `"vc_status":"reshedule"`, whatever it maybe. Its based on the person choice, to select the desired data. Maybe he accepts request after 1 minute or 30 minutes or rejects or reshedules. My duty is to fetch that data and accordingly reflect to UI.

Now to get data from that person, following are the methods I used:
Method 1:  useEffect()

```
const [newRequest, setNewRequest] = useState("")

const newData = () => {
try {
fetch(`https://www.api-example.com/video/requests`,{
method: get,
headers: {
   ApiKey:'hbhasdgasAsas',
   Authorization: '......'
}
}).then((data) => data.json()).then((data) => setNewRequest(data.vc_request))
}
}

useEffect(() => {
newData()
})
```

Then use newRequest data later in the code

Not feasible: useEffect is quite resource intensive and freezes the server at some particular time

Method 2: setInterval()

/* Same code as above, only few changes */

```
useEffect(() => {
setInterval(() =>{
 newData()
}, 10000)
}, [])
```

Not feasible: Here the server utilization is intensive although after 10 seconds but, still it freezes server

Ultimately My intention is to get VC status and accordingly reflect on the front-side without using useEffect or setInterval, even though its used but, should not be resource intensive. My duty is to manage only Front-side and fetch data from Server and reflect to UI

So what is the best optimal solution to get 'changed json data' from server and display to the front. Any solution highly appreciated

Comment: Sorry to say, if you are only in control of your front end, then your solution will indeed be only setInterval kind of solutions. You may want to see if the API provides somekind of webhook, which calls your own-server app when changes happened, and then you can choose to push it to your client in realtime using socket or firebase realtime database. If it doesn't, then your choice is limited.

Answer (score 4):

The only *good* way to do this is to change/add functionality to the *server* so that it can tell the client that information has changed, instead of the client having to request information from the server periodically.

This can be done with [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) (the same technology that Stack Exchange uses to give users realtime alerts on inbox messages, reputation changes, etc).

If you set up the server to have a socket endpoint that sends the data (JSON) back to the client:

- when the socket first connects, and
- when the data on the server changes

Then you should be able to have code something like the following on the frontend:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const socket = new WebSocket('wss://some-website.com/socket');
  socket.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    setNewRequest(parsed.vc_request);
  });
  return () => socket.close();
}, []);
```

If you do not have control over the server, and the server doesn't provide anything like this, you're out of luck, and repeated fetching that you've already mentioned is your only option.

If the server "freezes" after 10 seconds (not sure what the problem actually is there), I suppose you could try increasing the delay to something like a minute or two.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() =>{
    newData()
  }, 10000)
}, []);
```

> Not feasible: useEffect is quite resource intensive and freezes the server at some particular time

`useEffect` is not resource-intensive at all.

Comment: Perfectly said... I actually don't have any control over server and only option left is to use setInterval.

Comment: Can fcm (Firebase Cloud Messaging) be used here to get server data, one friend suggested me. What's your opinion?

Comment: I don't know what Firebase would have to do with this - either way, you'll have to request the API somehow, and it sounds like the server is really laggy, so I don't think requesting from somewhere other than the client would help things

Comment: Yes right, server is actually laggy. You guessed right

Comment: You could stick something in the middle to handle polling the outdated server, and then have that intermediary expose something better (like a websocket, server-sent event, or http2 server push). You probably should NOT handle setting up polling inside a useEffect.